# How to run sh file with absolute path and port number dynamically?

Tags: shell, jmeter

I am new shell scripting. I want to create a shell script which run jmeter-server.sh file located in a directory my shell script is:

```
SERVER_PORT="$2"  /opt/jmeter/apache-jmeter-"$1"/bin/jmeter-server
```

And I call like

```
sh shellFileName {folder Number like 1} {port number like 1410}
```

but problem is this work but the SERVER_PORT is ignored when I check the jmeter-server I find in running on port 1099 which is default port.
How do i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside [jmeter.properties](https://github.com/Capgemini/jmeter-server/blob/master/jmeter.properties) there are instructions for changing server port:

> ```
> # To change the port to (say) 1234:
> # On the server(s)
> # - set server_port=1234
> # - start rmiregistry with port 1234
> # On Windows this can be done by:
> # SET SERVER_PORT=1234
> # JMETER-SERVER
> #
> # On Unix:
> # SERVER_PORT=1234 jmeter-server
> #
> # On the client:
> # - set remote_hosts=server:1234
> ```

Comment: i know how run jmeter-server with different port. But i have to run like 10 server on 10 different port then i have type all the code. i want to create shell and just pass the folder number and port number.

Comment: just remove the double quotes